# Toggle Previous/Next Multiple Pages Javascript jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to be able to toggle between different html pages. For example, going from "section1.html" to "section2.html" etc. I've looked it up and some other solutions I see don't work for me. Can someone please help me?

Here is my code so far:
The next and previous aren't working. Keep in mind the body has texts and images for each page. I want both to move when I toggle. Or if there's a way to do it in the  file itself so the title changes as well, that would be great. I also have  in each of the html pages.

edit: I found a static solution. it would be "onclick="window.location='section1.html'" this according to the appropriate previous and next on each page. so if current page is section2, i would add that to the previous class tag. but how can i write this in js so it just does it sequentially instead of having to write it in every page?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".section").each(function(e) {
        if (e != 0)
            $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next").click(function(){
        if ($(".section").next().length != 0)
            $(".section").next().show().prev().hide();
        else {
            $(".section").hide();
            $(".section").show();
        }
        return false;
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        if ($(".section").prev().length != 0)
            $(".section").prev().show().next().hide();
        else {
            $(".section").hide();
            $(".section").show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.img
{
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="section">
  <div class = "container-text"> 
    <div class = "content"> 
      <div class = "row">
        <div class="col">
          <p> demo text</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class = "images"> 
    <div class = "container"> 
      <div class = "row">
        <div class="col">
          <p class="img"> demo img</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="section-nav" id="arrows">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 prev">
                        <p id="prev">
                            <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
                            previous
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 next">
                        <p id="next">next
                            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: so what you want is to switch between 2 html pages on click of prev and next button?

Comment: essentially, yes. Why i say that is because I also have links to those html pages on my index page. But there're more than two html pages. I just used two in this example. just letting you know incase. @seriously

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an iframe to load the site then use the prev and next buttons to change the src of the iframe. I think this is what you need. Feel free to comment if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** This works with multiple sites. Just update the array and the if statment if you need to add more sites.

```js
let linkArr = ["https://2ality.com/", "https://kentcdodds.com/blog/", "https://www.robinwieruch.de/blog", "https://daily-dev-tips.com/", "https://flaviocopes.com/"]

$('.fa-circle-arrow-left').on('click', function() {
  let currentSrc = $('.iframeWindow').attr('src')
  if (linkArr.indexOf(currentSrc) != 0) {
    $('.iframeWindow').attr('src', linkArr[linkArr.indexOf(currentSrc) - 1])
  }

})

$('.fa-circle-arrow-right').on('click', function() {
  let currentSrc = $('.iframeWindow').attr('src')
  if (linkArr.indexOf(currentSrc) != 4) {
    $('.iframeWindow').attr('src', linkArr[linkArr.indexOf(currentSrc) + 1])
  }
})
```

```css
.buttonCon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 3vw;
  padding-left: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 18%;
}

.buttonCon {
  font-size: 4vw;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.iframeWindow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.0.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-3B6NwesSXE7YJlcLI9RpRqGf2p/EgVH8BgoKTaUrmKNDkHPStTQ3EyoYjCGXaOTS" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="buttonCon"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-left"></i><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i></div>


<iframe class="iframeWindow" src="https://2ality.com/"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks but then how do you do it for multiple pages if you already have an attrc for left and right? I need it for multiple pages.

Comment: also are you saying the html should be child/wrapped to the iframe?

Comment: do you have a list of the pages? how many are there?

Comment: yes wrapping it in an iframe is the best option unless you are using electron js in which case web view is better.

Comment: 5 pages. And sorry I'm still new to coding, I don't know what electron js is. let me try wrapping it in an iframe. I'll be back in a min to let you know if it works or not.

Comment: ok give me a min

Comment: Tried the iframe method. Unfortunately it didn't work and actually took out my content so i couldn't see the webpage at all. @seriously

Comment: that shouldn't happen it's from your html code can you give me a link to a screenshot of what is happening.

Comment: it's literally just a blank white page @seriously

Comment: ok i will show you with real websites give me a min

Comment: check now i think this is what you need

Comment: ok btw when you wrap it in the html is it <iframe><html>  or <iframe> <!doctype html> <html> ? I tried both ways before but just want to be sure which one. also, in my case, would i substitute the link for "section1.html" etc? @seriously

Comment: oh no you don't wrap the HTML code in the iframe. The HTML code is a separate file. You are gonna get the name of the html file which is section1.html etc.. and inset it in the iframe src

Comment: oh ok. where would i put the iframe though based on my code? After the div for section nav?

Comment: you can position the iframe anywhere you want just get the iframes class name and apply css to it

Comment: ok so i tried that method and it made it look weird. like two sections on top of each other and the previous and next still dont work. not sure why. Thank you for trying though! @seriously

Comment: I mean this is the only way to do what you want. And iframes don't mess up your HTML but you could look for other options if you want.  Just telling you this for you not to waste your time.

Comment: Yeah im not sure why its not working for me though. Definitely tried it that way but looks weird on my end. I think there might be another way though. I initially did it with different sections on 1 html page but the pics and text were getting mixed matched. thanks for trying though! @seriously

Comment: I found a static solution. it would be "onclick="window.location='section1.html'" this according to the appropriate previous and next on each page. so if current page is section2, i would add that to the previous class tag.  but how can i write this in js so it just does it sequentially instead of having to write it in every page?